# Parametrization of the Lorentz Group

Tags: linear-algebra, special-relativity

The Lorentz group is the group of $4\times 4$ matrices that satisfy
$$\Lambda^T \eta \Lambda = \eta, \eta = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$
Is there a way to parametrize this group, just like how we may parametrize the group of 3-dimensional rotations (=$SO(3)$) using an axis of rotation and the angle of rotation?

Wikipedia has a [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation#Proper_transformations) for a Lorentz transformation with a boost along a direction $v$. Perhaps it's possible to write all Lorentz transformations in this way?

Comment: No, but there is a decomposition into the product of a rotation and boost.

Comment: See https://iopscience.iop.org/book/978-1-6817-4254-0/chapter/bk978-1-6817-4254-0ch1